# How to find Which User is updating the project and doing analysis report of project on sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube 8.3 and with the help of sonarqube APIs i want to build a project  so i need users information that which user is changing or correcting the bugs of project that was analysed on Sonarqube Server previously.
like suppose in one project many people are working and when one of them resolve their bugs and code smells that was given in previous analysis report on sonarqube UI so with the help of any APIs of Sonarqube will we able to find the user information such as their name and id something which can be helpful in my project that information will distingush that user.

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a good start is You can configure sonarqube to auto attribute the issue to the author identified by git infos

Comment: @Tokazio  like you mean with the help of github login info we will distingush the users